# Python 3.x isupper() for capital letter in a list using List Comprehension

Tags: python-3.x, list-comprehension

Could someone describe to me how I can have the same results as shown in approach 1, but using an approach 2? Both of which are using List Comprehension.

**Approach 1**

```
planets = 'MercuryVenusEarthMarsJupiterSaturnUranusNeptune'
capital_letters = [planet for planet in planets if planet.isupper()]
>>> ['M', 'V', 'E', 'M', 'J', 'S', 'U', 'N']
```

**Approach 2**

```
planets = ['Mercury', 'Venus', 'Earth', 'Mars', 'Jupiter', 'Saturn', 'Uranus', 'Neptune']
capital_letters = [planet for planet in planets if planet.islower()]
>>> []
```

**Some ideas:**

- To use slicing;

Comment: Why would you expect the same results? You have reversed the logic *and* changed the input.

Comment: Hey! Thank you commenting. That was exactly why I've decided to ask a question here.

Comment: What *is* your question, though? Given that your first approach gives the result you want, and there's no reason to expect that the second approach does and it indeed doesn't, what's the *problem*?

Comment: Hey, @jonrsharpe! Thank you for the follow up. Not quite right. My initial question was how to use the list comprehension approach to slice the first capital letter. After googling for some time, I've discovered that it could be done using slicing and the answer from @Jai proved that.

The problem was and, to some degree still is, - how to easily implement list comprehension without hard research\thinking for hours about that. And the answer is simple: practice. 

Well, it seems I've answered my own question with the help of Jai of course. =)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the below code, it gives the output as in approach 1 for your approach 2.

```
planets = ['Mercury', 'Venus', 'Earth', 'Mars', 'Jupiter', 'Saturn', 'Uranus', 'Neptune']
capital_letters = [planet[0] for planet in planets]
>>>['M', 'V', 'E', 'M', 'J', 'S', 'U', 'N']
```

Comment: Thank you! So, slicing was an asnwer =).